# "cabelo castanho/louro" or "cabelos castanhos/louros"?

Tags: número-gramatical

Both forms are grammatical, that's clear. This question, however, came to mind when a non-native speaker asked me which form should be used. My first impulse was to say that both are correct and that most people use that noun-phrase in the plural. Then I began to wonder whether there is any context where one form or the other would be idiomatic. For example, when we are talking about hair dye, describing a gorgeous woman, or any other context.

EDIT- My question is: Are there contexts where one form would be idiomatic and the other one wouldn't sound correct?

Do ponto de vista gramatical, ambas as formas estão corretas. Minha pergunta quanto ao número gramatical tem a ver com o fato de que uma imigrante que está aprendendo a língua portuguesa perguntou-me qual a forma correta. Meu primeiro impulso foi responder que ambas são corretas mas que eu, pessoalmente, uso o plural. Mas fiquei a "matutar" se não há situações em que o singular e/ou o plural sejam idiomáticos. Existem contextos onde uma forma seja idiomática e a outra não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta resposta baseia-se sobretudo na minha experiência em Portugal. Quando nos referimos à cabeleira toda de uma pessoa, o singular e o plural têm o mesmo significado, mas o singular é muito mais usado:

> Gosto do teu cabelo castanho;
>   Gosto dos teus cabelos castanhos.
>
> Quando era criança tinha o cabelo encaracolado;
>   Quando era criança tinha os cabelos encaracolados.
>
> Ela agora pintou o cabelo de azul;
>   Ela agora pintou os cabelos de azul.

Mas para referir a fios ou parte da cabeleira o plural já é mais usado:

> Começou-me a aparecer cabelo branco por volta dos trinta anos;
>   Começaram-me a aparecer cabelos brancos por volta dos trinta anos.

O plural é bastante usado para referir cabeleiras em geral, não de uma pessoa em particular; mas o singular é igualmente possível:

> Madeixas douradas ficam muito bem em cabelos escuros;
>   Madeixas douradas ficam muito bem em cabelo escuro.

Agora, apesar de usarmos sobretudo o singular para referir a cabeleira toda de uma pessoa, na música ouve-se frequentemente o plural, e soa muito bem. Quase sempre é um homem que canta louvores ao cabelo da mulher. Vá, todos a cantar:

> Índia, seus cabelos nos ombros caídos / negros como as noites que não têm luar
>   ([Gal Costa, *Índia*, 1973](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWKkUZ9N3bw) ou [Castatinha e Inhana, *Índia*, 1952.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVm7YA8o5ZU))
>
> Os teus cabelos, o teu sorriso / Não me deixaram mais dormir
>   [(Ângela Maria,*Os teus cabelos*.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyH6NVrs9yM)
>
> Quebrar tua boneca, Curuminha / Raspar os teus cabelos / E ir te exibindo pelos / Botequins
>   [(Chico Buarque, *Canção desnaturada*.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLbxQXHKh38)
>
> Um girassol nos teus cabelos / Batom vermelho / Morena flor do desejo
>   [(Alceu Valença, *Girassol*.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIEnH7cQNqs)
>
> Em teus cabelos de seda / Que perfume, que aroma sutil
>   [(Sílvio Caldas, *Há um segredo em teus cabelos*.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbRaEB8ldJ8)
>
> Negros teus cabelos cobriam teu corpo / tão cheia de amor te vi dançando
>   [(José Malhoa, *Cara de Cigana*.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHR14Y1Nr6A)

E aparece também na literatura:

> Uma simples flor nos teu cabelos claros
>   [(José Cardoso Pires, *Jogos de Azar*, 1999.)](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/contomes/17/texto.html)
>
> Nesse dia crescerão / sempre rosas, rosas / muitas rosas sobre o nosso amor / Para enfeitar os teus cabelos
>   [(Agostinho Neto, *Para enfeitar os teus cabelos*, 1956.)](http://www.agostinhoneto.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=571:dois-anos-de-distancia&catid=45:sagrada-esperanca&Itemid=233)

Na net o plural é muito mais comum do que a minha experiência da linguagem coloquial sugeriria. Muito disto é marketing também dirigido a mulheres, aproveitando o não sei quê de poético do plural.

Comment: Só conheço a gravação da Gal Costa (India teus cabelos nos ombros...).  typo = flor nos teu cabelos.   Nenhum uso idiomático para uma forma ou outra?  Como, por exemplo, em negro x preto, onde chá, azeitona e cerveja pedem sempre o "preto" e ovelha, nuvens e asa pedem sempre o "negro".

Comment: @Centaurus Para mim, *negro* tem sempre uma carga afetiva/emocional , enquanto *preto* é neutro. *Cabelos negros* é o que o cantor embevecido chama aos *cabelos pretos*.

Comment: @Centaurus Pois, parece que o original é mesmo da Gal Costa. Tentei descobrir as datas das várias canções, mas não é nada fácil.

Comment: @Centaurus Afinal à uma versão anterior, 1952; linkei.

Comment: Jacinto, acho que não me fiz entender.  Não estou discutindo negro x preto.  Minha pergunta é se existem usos idiomáticos para cabelo x cabelos, como  por exemplo "cabelo ruim" (termo pejorativo), "cabelo bom"  onde o singular é a forma preferida, ou "arrastou-a pelos cabelos" onde o plural é a regra.

Comment: Não saiu o link da canção de 1952.

Comment: @Centaurus Tenta outra vez. Há dois links naquela linha, o de 1973 e o de 1952 separados por "ou".

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple: I have brown air.

É a mesma coisa em português: **Tenho (o) cabelo castanho**. A côr do meu cabelo é castanho.

**Ninguem diria: **Tenho** (os) cabelos castanhos**.

Mas alguém poderia falar EM cabelos castanhos: Os cabelos castanhos são muito bonitos. Já seria outra coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Me recordo de uma regra ou dica onde o singular se refere a um fio de cabelo, e o plural a vários fios.

Sendo assim, "cabelo castanho" não é errado, mas pode ser exageradamente preciso e portanto impreciso ao que se quer dizer, quando na verdade você está se referindo ao couro cabeludo e não a apenas um fio de cabelo.

Numa pesquisa rápida encontrei algo similar mas falando sobre o corte dos cabelos, contudo confere com o que me recordo sobre o assunto entre cabelo = 1 fio, cabelos = múltiplos fios:

http://www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/1766220

Entretanto, embora a regra formal possa ser essa, na prática apenas em anúncios vejo o uso do plural, no coloquial as pessoas não usam o plural. Mas para a palavra "pelos" as pessoas usam o plural.

Answer (score -1):

*Cabelo castanho* é gramaticalmente correto. Uma vez que "cabelo" é um nome incontável, não se pode acrescentar *s* ao mesmo. Atualmente, é normal se dizer: *Eu tenho cabelos castanhos*, mas tenha em mente que não é gramaticalmente correto. Então eu tenho duas sugestões:

> *Formalmente:* Eu tenho cabelo castanho / Meu cabelo é castanho.
>
> *Informalmente:* Eu tenho cabelos castanhos / Meus cabelos são castanhos.

Comment: O plural está errado.

Comment: O que quis dizer? Que a forma do plural não é correta por que o nome é singular? Sim, então você está certo, mas como eu disse no meu post: Cabelo/s castanho/s é usado também (em informal contextos)